# Relate HREFLANG tags to the current page

Tags: html, seo, href, head

I've been tasked with updating our hreflang tags to relate to the site that the user is on. For example...

Currently it's hard coded like `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en" />` but say the user has navigated to the `products/tabletimes` page so the URL is actually `https://www.example.com/products/tabletimes`. Is there a way to code the tags in `<head>` to reflect this?

So instead it could be `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/products" hreflang="en" />` and/or `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/products/tabletimes" hreflang="en" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking thoroughly through the `Context` variable I found that the `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` property does relate to the path of the page you're on. You can use that property in `<link rel="alternate" href="@string.Format("https://www.example.com{0}", absoluteUrlPath)" hreflang="en" />` to reflect which page you're on in the other corresponding laguages that have a matching page.